# Prevent sign-extension during byte array to string conversion

Tags: java, string, byte, data-conversion

The BYTEMASK flag in the sample code keeps the value from being signed-extended when it's converted to an int. How is this flag preventing the conversion form being sign-extended?

```
private final static int BYTEMASK = 0xFF;

private static String byteArrayToDecimalString(byte[] bArray) {
        StringBuilder rtn = new StringBuilder();
        for(byte b : bArray) 
            rtn.append(b & BYTEMASK).append(" ");
        return rtn.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The value *is* sign-extended.  But then the mask removes the sign extension.

Comment: how is it removing the sign-extension?

Comment: It does becase the sign bit (1), when binary-anded with 0, becomes 0. Because 1 & 0 is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned in comments, the bytemask does not prevent the sign extension, instead it undoes it. For example:

```
0x80 -- sign extend -> 0xffffff80 -- mask with 0xff -> 0x00000080
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm stepping through the code in the debugger to understand the process.